# Cleveref - change crefname for paragraphs to include paragraph title

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I'd like to change the `\crefname` for paragraphs so that it produces "paragraph " instead of the numbering

The regular latex command `\nameref` already produces the title but without "paragraph" in front

So far I've tried variations of the below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{paragraph}{paragraph \nameref}{paragraphs \nameref}
\Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph \nameref}{Paragraphs \nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\paragraph{First paragraph}\label{par:1}

This is a reference to \cref{par:1}. %Should produce This is a reference to paragraph First paragraph.


\end{document}
```

I believe the `\crefname` command can't take the `\nameref` variable in it's definition...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your crefname for `paragraph` never comes into action, since there's no label for `paragraph` here. `\label{par:1}` refers to the section, not the paragraph, since `First paragraph` is not numbered, so the label is not what you expect

Comment: You're right, `\nameref` should not appear in the `\crefname` setup

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to reference the short paragraph name, e.g., `\paragraph[Short name]{First paragraph}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding by the O.P. apparently:

Unless the `secnumdepth` counter is not set to the value of '4' (or higher) the `\paragraph` will not be numbered at all and `\refstepcounter` is not executed, so `\label{par:1}` refers to the last counter being ref-stepped (which is `section` in this particular case!)

It's also 'wrong' to use `\section{...}` and then `\paragraph`. The `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` commands shouldn't be omitted.

If they are omitted, the macro `\theparagraph` must be changed too to prevent ugly `1.0.0.1` numbering style.

A `\paragraph` is not a paragraph in the usual sense, i.e. some text visually separated in the running text -- `\paragraph` is meant to be used as another structure level unit (if really needed at all!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
\Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}


\begin{document}
This is a reference to \cref{par:1}. %Should produce This is a  reference to paragraph First paragraph.
Another reference to \Cref{par:1}%
\clearpage
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection title}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\paragraph{First paragraph}\label{par:1}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Update with a 'fake' `\cnameref` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}



\crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
\Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cnameref}[1]{%
  \namecref{#1} \nameref{#1}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Cnameref}[1]{%
  \nameCref{#1} \nameref{#1}%
}





\makeatother



\begin{document}

This is a reference to \cnameref{par:1}. %Should produce This is a reference to paragraph First paragraph.

Another reference to \Cnameref{par:1}

\clearpage
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection title}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\paragraph{First paragraph}\label{par:1}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! This helps a lot already. However, the 'end-goal' is to print 'First paragraph' instead of '1.1.1.1'. That is why I thought somehow the paragraph's title needs to be included in the definition of \crefname{paragraph}

Comment: @Aad: Why don't you use `\nameref` then -- it will print the title of the paragraph etc.

Comment: because that only prints the title and not paragraph in front of its title. The point is that I want to avoid too long numbering for paragraph cross-references in my text. So the regular use of 'section 1.2' is fine, but I prefer 'paragraph <par title>' instead of paragraph 1.3.2.4.5

Comment: @Aad: Must `paragraph` appear in the hyperlink as well or is the `par title` sufficient in the hyperlink? See the update please