# In-line \paragraph{} and \subparagraph{} commands

Tags: titlesec, paragraphs, cleveref

I am attempting to find a way to create a clickable reference link that works similar to how a clickable reference link can be created to link to a chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph. What I am looking for is a way to have a clickable reference link that is **in-line** with the normal text. I have searched for a LaTeX package as a way to do this, but have not found any package that would allow this function.

One idea I've been researching is how might use the \paragraph{ } and \subparagraph{ } commands to do what I'd like to, particularly since it is highly unlikely that I will otherwise use the \paragraph{ } and \subparagraph{ } commands as they were originally intended ... as proper titles.

I've been researching how the clickable reference link for the paragraph and subparagraphs work to see if I might use the \paragraph{ } and \subparagraph{ } titles as proxies for the **in-line** clickable reference link function I am looking for. With certain settings, I've been able to get rather close to what it is I am looking for, with one rather intractable exception, which is demonstrated in the MWE. I am unable, and don't know if it is even possible, to work with \titleformat{\paragraph} and \titleformat{\subparagraph} to make the \paragraph{} and \subparagraph{} commands print **in-line** with the surrounding text, as demonstrated in the MWE.

As someone far-less-than-an-expert in LaTeX, I may be completely missing an obvious package that can be used to create an **in-line** clickable reference link. My apologies if that is the case. I may also be "barking-up-the-wrong-tree" in my attempt to somehow adjust the \titleformat{\paragraph} and \titleformat{\subparagraph} to make the \paragraph{ } and \subparagraph{ } commands print **in-line** with the surrounding text. Apologies also if that is something that cannot be done with the current version of the \titleformat{\paragraph} and \titleformat{\subparagraph} commands.

I am all ears and eyes if someone has a way to adopt the \paragraph{ } and \subparagraph{ } commands to print **in-line** with the surrounding text, or if not, any ideas as to how I might otherwise do so.

Much of the following MWE code was cobbled together from "[How to reference \paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/how-to-reference-paragraph)", and "[Cleveref - change crefname for paragraphs to include paragraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320632/cleveref-change-crefname-for-paragraphs-to-include-paragraph-title)".

Thanks for reading!

P.S. The MWE code needs to be run twice for all the LaTeX commands to work properly!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
\Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}

\crefname{subparagraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
\Crefname{subparagraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cnameref}[1]{%
  \namecref{#1} \nameref{#1}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Cnameref}[1]{%
  \nameCref{#1} \nameref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}


\begin{document}

\clearpage

I'd like to see this \paragraph{Paris paragraph label}\label{par:Paris} to appear in-line with the text, as you can see on the next line. \par
.\par

I'd like the \textbf{Paris paragraph label} to appear, as it does here, in-line with the text (without the extra space padding that appears after the \textbf{Paris paragraph label}). \par
.\par

I'd really like to see this \subparagraph{London subparagraph label}\label{subpar:London} to appear in-line with the text, as you can see on the next line. \par
.\par

I'd really like the \textbf{London subparagraph label} to appear, as it does here, in-line with the text (without the extra space padding that appears after the \textbf{London paragraph label}). \par
.\par

\newpage

This is a reference to the \cnameref{par:Paris} that appears  on \cpageref{par:Paris}. \par
.\par

This is a reference to the \Cnameref{subpar:London} that appears  on \cpageref{subpar:London}, (but I noticed that it appears that a space is missing between the words Paragraph and London-why? I don't know, but it would be nice to know how to fix it). \par
 \newpage
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should define a new command.

Comment: you can use \hypertarget and \hyperref from hyperref package, you do not want  section heading commands like \paragraph

Comment: @David Carlisle - Perfect! \hypertarget Works! ... Thank you. I've added the \pagetarget macro to include the \hypertarget page number ... I'll document what I've done when I've had some sleep. Thanks again. (I could NOT however, get the gmiflink Package to work ... may be too out of date w too many bugs - more later!)

Comment: @David Carlisle - your comment was an 'answer' that proved to be better than a direct answer to my question. If you'll post a quick one-line 'answer', I'll gladly accept your answer so you can get the proper credit. Thanks again ... \hypertarget Works!